# How can I compute $P(X < b)$ if I have continuous r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ where $f(x,y) = 2e^{-x}e^{-2y}$

Tags: calculus, probability

How can I compute $P(X < b)$ for $b>0$ if I have continuous r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ where $f(x,y) = 2e^{-x}e^{-2y}$ defined on the region $0 < x < \infty$, $0 <y <\infty$ and $0$ otherwise?

My approach is to recognize that for any subset $A$:

$$
P(X \in A) = P(X \in A, Y \in (-\infty, \infty)) = \int_{A}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dydx
$$

From this:

$$
P(X < b) = \int_{0}^{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2e^{-x}e^{-2y}dydx
$$

However, the integral inside evaluates to $0$ and hence I get $0$. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The support of $Y$ is $[0;\infty)$ not $(-\infty;\infty)$.  Reevaluate the bounds on the integral.

Comment: Also, if you are more familiar with these kinds of distribution, you can immediately see that $X, Y$ are independent as the joint pdf can be factorized and the support is rectangular. This can help you to confirm the marginal pdf of $X$ found by the inner integration.

Answer (score 0):

Reexamine the bounds of the integration, since the support of $Y$ is $[0;\infty)$ not $(-\infty;\infty)$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<b) & = \int_0^b\int_0^\infty 2 e^{-x}e^{-2y}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\[1ex] & = \int_0^b e^{-x}\operatorname d x \\[1ex] & = 1-e^{-b}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your bounds are wrong. Also, take advantage of shortcuts
\begin{align*}
P(X < b) &= \int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}2e^{-x}e^{-2y}dydx\\
&=\int_0^b e^{-x}\left(\int_0^\infty2e^{-2y}\,dy\right)\,dx\tag 1\\
&=\int_0^be^{-x}\cdot 1\,dx\tag 2\\
&=F_X(b)\\
&=1-e^{-b}
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$, I recognize that this the density of a exponential distribution with mean $1/2$
and in $(2)$ I recognize the integral as the cdf of a exponential distribution with mean $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = (1e^{-x})(2e^{-2y}) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$$
over $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent; furthermore, $X$ is exponential with mean $1$. Hence, $$\mathbb{P}(X < b) = 1-e^{-b}\text{.}$$